# After pulling data from website, How to render it with component?

Tags: reactjs

I am pulling data from one website( url:https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/) & data is getting displayed in console. I am using "axios" lib to fetch the data.
But I want to render it with component. How to do it?

This is my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

var Country ;

var fetchData = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/',
});

fetchData.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/')
            .then(
                function (response){
                    console.log(response)
                    Country = response.data
                    console.log(Country)            
                });


console.log(Country);


export default  React.createClass({

shouldCompoentUpdate: function(Country,response){
    return true;
    },

render(){
        return(
                <div>
                    <h3>States test</h3>
                </div>                      
            )   
    }           
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are doing it wrong. First of all please read about React Component [lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) and [Loading Initial Data example](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html). You need to get your data in `componentDidMount()` hook and set state when data is received.

```
React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { country: '' }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var fetchData = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/',
    });

    fetchData.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/')
    .then(function (response) {
      this.setState({ country: response.data});          
    }.bind(this));
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div>{this.state.country}</div>
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I have one doubt. How to display it as this data is in JSON format?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invariant Violation: setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables.

Comment: @maharshioza sorry, made a typo there. Here is working sample, but using jquery instead of axios (easy to switch back) http://jsbin.com/safahogawe/edit?html,js,console,output